# converting a string into a file name

Tags: python

I am new to programming. I have to write a function that ultimately loads a series of images. It takes user input of the beginning of the file name and how many files there are, then I create a loop that loads all the images and stores them in a list. An example: file names are da_1.gif, da_2.gif, da_3.gif. User input would be image= da, n= 3. In my loop, I have updated the image variable to create the correct name of the file, but when I run the program it comes back with an error that the file name doesn't exist. The file is saved in the same folder as my code file, so I am assuming the error is that it is not reading the string as a file name. How do I create a code that will successfully load the images?

Here is my code:

```
def loadImages():
  images= []
  image= input("Enter the abbreviation that describes the subject of the photograph:")
  n= int(input("Enter the number of images you want to load:"))
  if n >= 3 and n <= 16:
    for i in range (1, n+1):
      width= getWidth() * i
      height= 0
      i= str(i)
      image= image + "_" + i + ".gif"
      image_2= loadImage(image)
      drawImage(image, width, height)
      images.append(image)
```

Comment: Add a `print(image)` after your `image= image + "_" + i + ".gif"` to see the file names you are producing.

Comment: You are changing the image variable in each loop iteration, such that in the second iteration you get ‘da_1.gif_2.gif’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `image = image + "_" + i + ".gif"` you are re-assigning the `image` variable, but it doesn't look like that was your intent. You want `image` to hold the abbreviation so that the file name can be constructed from it. Also, you probably don't want to pass the file path to `drawImage`, but the image object instead. To fix, simply use a temp variable:

```
  image_path = image + "_" + i + ".gif"
  image_2= loadImage(image_path)
  drawImage(image_2, width, height)
  images.append(image_2)
```